# Processing Blend Modes and 3D

Tags: 3d, processing

Do blend modes in Processing work with 3D? I have two leaf shaped objects which overlap. I am using PeasyCam to rotate around these objects. In the first picture below I have no blend mode applied. The second picture shows a different angle so you can see how the objects are offset on the z axis in 3D space.

The third picture shows what I get when I apply the MULTIPLY blend mode. I'd expect just the overlapping areas to have the blend applied?

[image: No Blend Mode - Angle 1]

[image: No blend mode =- Angle 2]

[image: MULTIPLY blend mode]

Answer (score 1):

OK kinda worked it out myself - and learnt the problem of depth sorting in 3D!

If I swap the draw order of the objects around it works as expected.